# How to know if my android device has been hacked, using Kali Linux?

Tags: exploit, android, forensics, kali-linux

Can we locate files, in android device, using android studio? I'm talking about files which have been uploaded to the device using kali linux - payloads / exploits?

Are they delivered using update features?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so simple and absolute way as you expect! Hackers use (local - remote) exploits to install at least a backdoor on device. The backdoor in most of the cases is an APK (sometimes a binded app).

So here's the way Android AV's scan for exploits (also malwares):

1. AV have a database of exploit or binded **APK signs** And other **exploit unique signs** (like: files on sd, ...)
2. On every scan you check installed APK sings with your DB (if one of the sings match you detected an exploit)
3. You should have an analysis team and new exploit discovery strategies, to update your DB regularly.

**Important Note:**  If your AV have **Root** access there are many more advanced detection techniques you can implement (Network and packet scanning, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Without root access to the phone, you're not going to be able to tell. And you don't get root access without hacking the phone. So the only possible answers are "yes" or "unknown" - there is no "no" answer to the question.